# Vue Composition Api - watch property imported from external composition function

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have external composition function where i declare property like this:

```
export default function useDescription() {
  const description = ref('');

  return {
    description
  }
}
```

Then, I would like to import this property in other component, inside the setup method and watch for the changes like this:

```
setup() {
  const { description } = useDescription();
  watch(description, (value) => {
    //do sth
  })
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ref property outside the function in order to be accessible from both components :

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
const description = ref("");
export default function useDescription() {
  return { description };
}
```

and

```
setup() {
  const { description } = useDescription();
  watch(()=>description, (value) => {
    //do sth
  })
}
```

Comment: Im afraid it doesnt work :/ the only one difference is the event is now triggered once because of the immediate:true option, but future changes are ignored.

Comment: How are you doing that future changes?

Comment: Input updates the value. When i watch this property inside useDescription function, everything works perfectly.

Comment: I have created the sandbox where my problem is shown https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-microservice-i98sb?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: The key was to move ref property outside the composable function. Now it works even without  immediate:true, deep:true options